# Appcelerator Android Service background stops

Tags: android, service, background, appcelerator

I have a problem with appcelerator, regarding to android background service.
The service starts, and when I press the home button, the service is still running, and also when I click the back button.
But when I remove my app from the recent apps list(pressing long home button) , the service stops.
This is my code for the call service:

```
var SECONDS = 6;
    // every 10 minutes
    var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent({
        url : 'myservice.js'
    });
    intent.putExtra('interval', SECONDS * 1000);
    intent.putExtra('message_to_echo', num);

    //in millimeter
    var service = Titanium.Android.createService(intent);

    service.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
    //  num++;
    //  alert(num);
    });

    service.start();
```

And this is the file service code:

```
var service = Titanium.Android.currentService;
var intent = service.intent;
var message = intent.getStringExtra("message_to_echo");

var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP,
    // Substitute the correct classname for your application
    className : 'com.mappa.angeli.MappaActivity',
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

// Create a PendingIntent to tie together the Activity and Intent
var pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
    intent: intent,
    flags: Titanium.Android.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
});

// Create the notification
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    // icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
   // icon: Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.my_icon,
    contentTitle: 'Something Happened',
    contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
   // tickerText: 'Our app made a notification!',
    defaults:Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.DEFAULT_SOUND,
    contentIntent: pending
});
// Send the notification.
Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

How can I run the service continously, such as whats app or something like that?
Please help me, it's very important.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is currently not possible with Appcelerator. Even though native app are doing it. There are similar post of this requirement, Still no reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

First let me give you a little perspective about your questions so that you'll be able to understand the logic behind.

> **My Understanding about your Question and Conclusion**

What you are asking for is not possible even in the native app, specifically if you are using the background services.

> **Why it is doing so?**
>
> Because the application is no longer in service anymore. The app is
>   forcefully removed from the background and hence the OS stops all its
>   services running in the background to clear the Memory.

What most of the default players do to play music is the use the foreground service and show a notification that the app is running and is processing something in the background (in this case playing the songs).

> **Options that you could look for**

I would suggest you to add up '**push notification service**' to your app rather than going in for '**background service**'. You will get the notification even if your app is not in the background (same as it is in WhatsApp).

You could follow the below link to implement the **GCM push services** for android:
http://www.tidev.io/2013/12/20/using-gcm-for-android-push-notifications-with-acs/

Hope this helps.

**Good Luck, Cheers**